# How to click on calendar using Robotium

Tags: android, robotium, android-calendar

**I want to click on day of Calendar and see my Event detail.** This is calendar screen.
[image]

**And this is what i want to see after clicking:**
 [image]

**How to achieve this using Robotium ?**

I used public [ExtendedCalendarView](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView) calendarView;

Comment: show us some effort here... have you tried anything?

Comment: didnt find any code to click on calendar, there is only this `solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(com.hh.android.R.id.DueDate));
 solo.setDatePicker(0, 2014, 9, 13);` to pick date with datepicker.

Comment: write the error message

Comment: I didnt find any code related to this, so there is no error code :)

Comment: try solo.clickOnText("14").

Comment: tried before, no luck. ALso tried `solo.clickOnButton("14")`

Comment: solo.getView(id) and use the image id